# How to force https and www on symfony 4

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem that I don't understand with symfony. I would like to force https and www on my .htaccess, but I don't understand anything with symfony.

Here is my .htaccess inside www file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

And in my public file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I don't know what I need to write and where ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The first two lines are for redirecting to https, the second two lines for www.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```